# Periodic Boundary Conditions in Atomistic Simulation Environment

Tags: atomic-simulation-environment, periodic-boundary-conditions

Consider the following atoms object.
`atoms_al = ase.build.fcc111('Al', size=(1,2,2), vacuum=16.0, orthogonal=True)`
To set the periodic boundary conditions along the x-direction I use:
`atoms_al.pbc=np.array([1,0,0],dtype=bool)`
I am trying to understand what exactly changes, mathematically, in the atoms_al object once the periodic boundary conditions are applied? Will some attributes of the atoms_al object change once the pbc are applied?
If so, what can they be for example?

I have looked up the source code to find what atoms.pbc does to the atoms object but I did not have any luck. If you could please point me to where I can see the implementation, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Cross posted on matsci: https://matsci.org/t/periodic-boundary-conditions/37194

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The PBC attribute in ASE is used for:

- finding nearest neighbours
- input for calculators that may use that information (dftd3, dmol, etc.)
- creation of surfaces
- finding the Bravais lattice
- certain constraints
- certain optimization strategies

Nothing is *per se* changed in the object. But much of the functionality of ASE depends on that attribute.

If you are interested then you could grep for the pbc uses `grep '\.pbc' **/*.py`
which will list where it is used.

Comment: +1 for a very quick, yet thorough answer! That's the way to do it! Just in case you didn't know, we have an [ASE chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111469/ase) too :)

Comment: Thanks! Especially for the grep command.